# Getting 'Could not load NIB in bundle' error

Tags: swift3, frameworks, nib, uitableview

I'm creating a framework that makes a RESTful call to a web-server and returns a custom UITableView. The iOS client imports my framework and makes an instance of the one public class and calls the one method to return an UITableView.

However I am getting an "NSInternalInconsistencyException: 'Could not load NIB in bundle'" error and can't seem to figure out what's causing the error:

[image]

I have the default tableview cell created via xib in my framework and in my custom tableview class, I register the cell in my viewDidLoad():[image]

It compiles fine in my framework but whenever I try to use the method to get a tableview, I'm getting the error. Any idea what's the issue?

Few things I tried / checked:

- Made sure that my xib's target is selected to be the framework's.

Comment: you can try from here it's working fine. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my error.

Not sure if my understanding / explanation is correct but I need to register the UINib to the class that is going to be using the custom tableview cells.
[image]